# How to pass foreign key model instance from django to reactjs using axios

Tags: python, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, axios

I have the `address` model which is basically foreign key aggregation to different other models. And `user` Model that has an address ID. every user has an address. and every address is combination of other parameters.
Now, i want to access these address parameters from user object instance.

Models.py

```
class AddressType(models.Model):
    add_type_name = models.CharField(_("Address Type"), max_length=30)
    add_type_code = models.CharField(_("Address Type Code "), max_length=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.add_type_name


class AddressProvince(models.Model):
    add_prov_name = models.CharField(_("Province Name"), max_length=20)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.add_prov_name

class AddressBranch(models.Model):
    add_branch_name = models.CharField(_("Branch Name"), max_length=100)
    add_branch_code = models.CharField(_("Branch Code"), max_length=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.add_branch_name
    

class AddressDepartment(models.Model):
    add_dept_name = models.CharField(_("Department Name"), max_length=150)
    add_dept_code = models.CharField(_("Department Code "), max_length=5)
    add_dept_floor = models.PositiveIntegerField(_("Department Floor"), default=0)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.add_dept_name
    
class AddressContact(models.Model):
    add_cont_name = models.CharField(_("Contact Name"), max_length=200)
    add_cont_position = models.CharField(_("Contact Position"), max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.add_cont_name

class AddressSection(models.Model):
    add_sec_name = models.CharField(_("Section Name"), max_length=250)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Address Section"
    def __str__(self):
        return self.add_sec_name
    

class Address(models.Model):
    add_type = models.ForeignKey(AddressType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name="address_type")
    add_prov = models.ForeignKey(AddressProvince, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True,related_name="address_province")
    add_branch = models.ForeignKey(AddressBranch, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True,related_name="address_branch")
    add_dept = models.ForeignKey(AddressDepartment, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True, related_name="address_department")
    add_contact = models.ForeignKey(AddressContact, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True, related_name="address_contact")
    add_section = models.ForeignKey(AddressSection, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True, related_name="address_section")
    add_is_sys = models.BooleanField(_("Is System User?"), default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.add_section.add_sec_name

class UserGroup(models.Model):
    user_group_name = models.CharField(_("Group"), max_length=100)
    user_group_code = models.CharField(_("Group Code"), max_length=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_group_code


class User(models.Model):
    user_name = models.CharField(_("Name"), max_length=180)
    user_password = models.CharField(_("Password"), max_length=100)
    user_email = models.CharField(_("Email"), max_length=150)
    user_AZB = models.CharField(_("AZB"), max_length=20)
    user_group = models.ForeignKey(UserGroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user_group")
    user_position = models.CharField(_("Position"), max_length=100)
    user_address = models.ForeignKey(Address, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user_address")
```

And on `views.py` i have the following, I want to send all user data including address detail from django to react.

```
@csrf_exempt
def userLogin(request):
    email = request.POST.get('user_email')
    password = request.POST.get('user_password')
    user  = models.User.objects.get(user_email = email , user_password = password)
    userData = ser.serialize('json', [user])
    userAddress = fetch_address(user.user_address.id)
    if user: 
        return JsonResponse(
            userData, userAddress, safe=False)
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'bool': False})
```

And on my react Login.jsx, I want to store data like this so i can access user data anywhere through the website.

```
  const submitForm = (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault()
    const userFormData = new FormData;
    userFormData.append('user_email', userData.user_email)
    userFormData.append('user_password', userData.user_password)
    
      axios.post(baseURL+'/login/', userFormData).
      then((res)=>{
        // sessionStorage.setItem('userLoggedIn', true)
        // sessionStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(res.data.user[0]))
      }).catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err.response.data)
      })
  }
```

In above section i want to store the data object for the user including his address information
such as `User->Address->type->type_code` and `User->Address->province->province_name` From django to reactjs.

I tried creating a function that returns the address information for the user however it gives an error `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

```
def fetch_address(add_id):
    
    findAddress = models.Address.objects.get(pk=add_id)
    data = []
    if findAddress:
        data.append({"add_id": add_id})
    if findAddress.add_type:
        addType = models.AddressType.objects.get(pk=findAddress.add_type.id)
        data.append ({
            "add_type_name" : addType.add_type_name,
            "add_type_code" : addType.add_type_code,
            "add_type_id" : findAddress.add_type.id,
        })
    if findAddress.add_prov:
         addProv = models.AddressProvince.objects.get(pk=findAddress.add_prov.id)
         data.append({
            "add_prov_name" : addProv.add_prov_name,
            "add_prov_id" : findAddress.add_prov.id,
        })
    if findAddress.add_branch:
        addBranch = models.AddressBranch.objects.get(pk=findAddress.add_branch.id)
        data.append({
            "add_branch_code" : addBranch.add_branch_code,
            "add_branch_name" : addBranch.add_branch_name,
            "add_branch_id" : findAddress.add_prov.id,
        })
    if findAddress.add_dept:
        addDept = models.AddressDepartment.objects.get(pk=findAddress.add_dept.id)
        data.append({
            "add_dept_code": addDept.add_dept_code,
            "add_dept_name": addDept.add_dept_name,
            "add_dept_floor": addDept.add_dept_floor,
            "add_dept_id": findAddress.add_dept.id
        })
    if findAddress.add_contact:
        addContact = models.AddressContact.objects.get(pk=findAddress.add_contact.id)
        data.append({
            "add_cont_code": addContact.add_cont_name,
            "add_cont_pos": addContact.add_cont_position,
            "add_cont_id": findAddress.add_contact.id
        })
    if findAddress.add_section:
        addSection = models.AddressSection.objects.get(pk=findAddress.add_section.id)
        data.append({
            "add_sec_name": addSection.add_sec_name,
            "add_sec_id": findAddress.add_contact.id
        })
    if data:
        return json.dumps(data) 
    else:
        return {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so the good news is that what you are trying to do is fairly common and the basis of most API... so there are many tools that can do it for you. Those tools are called **serializers**. In short, they will transform your **model and its relations** into a JSON object based on your instructions. (*Serializers do more than that, but in our specific case, this is what we will focus on*)

One of the best tools for the job is the [Django Rest Framework package (aka DRF)](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/). Its jobs is literally to help you build an API within Django, with minimal code. And it also provides model serializer that take care of transforming your models and its relations into JSON

```py
# models.py
from django.db import models

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, related_name='books', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

```py
# serializers.py
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Author, Book

class AuthorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ['id', 'name']

class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = AuthorSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'author']
```

```py
# views.py
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from .models import Book
from .serializers import BookSerializer

class BookDetail(APIView):
    def get(self, request, book_id):
        book = Book.objects.get(id=book_id)
        serializer = BookSerializer(book)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

I highly suggest you check the DRF website/tutorial as it would entirely fit your needs, even more so if you plan on having more API endpoints like that

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have serializer classes, my question is how can i access in your example, author Author name by book such as `book->author->author_name` in my react component.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Based on the example, `BookSerializer` has a `author` field which itself is a `AuthorSerializer` that has a `name` field. So the serializer_data (or book_data) should be a dict and the name would be `serializer_data["author"]["name"]`. So in JS, it should be `book_data.author.name`

Comment: Thanks Jordan, It was the `Serializer Depth` property that did the job